# Embedded compilation not liking char *var[]={"data","data"};

Tags: c, embedded, char

I'm working on a [PIC 18f4685](http://www.robokits.co.in/datasheets/PIC18F4685.pdf) using MPLabs [C18 C-compiler](http://abarry.org/pic/C18_User_Guide_51288j.pdf) and I'm having issue when I try and create an array of phrases that I want to print out to my LCD.

If I use Codeblocks with gcc and enter this code it prints out what I expect to the console...`test1 test2 test3 test4`:

```
char *test[]={"test1","test2","test3","test4"};
printf("%s %s %s %s\n",test[0],test[1],test[2],test[3]);
```

However, if I use this code in C18:

```
    char *phrase[]={"test1","test2"};
```

I get warnings saying `type qualifier mismatch in assignment` and when I program the chip it spits out garbage to the LCD, which I kinda expected it would do.

What is the proper way to declare my phrases because something is obviously incorrect?

Comment: That *is* the proper way. Either it's not a true C implementation or at the very least it's not a conforming implementation.

Comment: In the second case, the compiler is wrong (or out of sync). It is not an assignment but an initialiser. Re: *out of sync*: the 2nd fragment would be wrong if it occured inside a struct declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently string literals are `rom const char[N]` in MPLab C. So you need to declare your object like this:

```
rom const char *rom test[]={"test1","test2","test3","test4"};
```

In [MPLAB C18 C COMPILER USER'S GUIDE](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51288f.pdf), there is a chapter named ISO DIVERGENCES (2.7) and 2.7.3 refers to string literals.

From 2.7.3:

> When using MPLAB C18, a string table in program memory can be declared as:
>
> ```
> rom const char table[][20] =   { "string 1", "string 2",  
>                                  "string 3", "string 4" }; 
> rom const char *rom table2[] = { "string 1", "string 2", 
>                                  "string 3", "string 4" };
> ```

Comment: Can you give a URL reference to support this?

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51288f.pdf section 2.7.3 (ISO divergences)

Comment: Just tried that syntax. No more mismatch assignments but getting suspicious pointer conversion. Realized that print to lcd was void lcd_puts(unsigned char *s) so changed rom const char phrase[] to unsigned now getting mismatch at lcd_puts(phrase[0]);  and garbage output.

Comment: When your program runs out of flash, there are two possibilities for initialized data - it can be used in the flash, such that the unsigned char* array member points to flash, or somewhat more typically it can be used from ram, with the pointer pointing there, and the necessity for something to copy it there during program initialization.  Printing out the actual pointer address and comparing to the linker map or datasheet should give you an indication of what is (and isn't) happening.  If you determine you are using a ram copy, examine the initializer or observe it in a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I think @awoodland's (now deleted) answer has essentially the right idea.

The declaration:

```
char *phrase[] = {"test1", "test2"};
```

is perfectly valid C, but it is potentially problematic.  C string literals are not `const`, but attempting to modify them has undefined behavior.  (They're actually `const` in C++, which would make the above declaration illegal.)

It's likely that C18 is enforcing `const`ness for string literals.  If so, you should be able to avoid the error by adding a `const` keyword:

```
const char *phrase[] = {"test1", "test2"};
```

Adding `const` here is a good idea anyway, since without it the compiler can't diagnose an attempt to modify one of the strings.

Note that gcc's `-Wwrite-strings` option enables a similar non-standard feature.

**EDIT :**

See ouah's answer. The `const` is not required in standard C, but it's a good idea to use it anyway. For this particular implementation, you also need to add a system-specific `rom` keyword.

Comment: Fair enough. But why would it "spit out garbage to the LCD" without the const ?

Comment: @cnicutar: I think ouah's answer probably explains that; it's the `rom`, not the `const`.